when i run flutter on terminal return error Unable to connect to Chrome debug port: 52181
I'm currently learning Flutter and have installed all the necessary programs to run it on my computer. My operating system is Windows 11, and I've installed JDK 8, CmdLine, Dart SDK, and Flutter, and set up the environment variables. I've also installed a few emulators such as Pixel 8 API and Pixel 5.
However, when I run the flutter run command from the terminal inside VSCode, I encounter the following error:
Unable to connect to Chrome debug port: 52181
SocketException: The remote computer refused the network connection.
(OS Error: The remote computer refused the network connection.
, errno = 1225), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 52182

I've also tried changing the port using flutter run --web-port=55000, but it didn't make any difference. Can anyone please guide me on how to resolve this issue?
Thank you.
and i try to (flutter run) when the simulator was on.
after that, return this errors :
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              3.7s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
remember it : i try it from IRAN.
